# Get to second level array in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

im more of a designer and less of a programmer so any help is greatly appreciated. The idea behind this project is to generate a dropdown menu using the "name" from the data json and when selected the "stock" information will appear as well. I've been able to get to the "name":"Pantone 12345" but when i try to access the name of the stocks i get and error saying it can't find property "name"

here is my json

```
var data = 

[
    {   "id":"Pantone 12345",
        "name":"Pantone 12345",
        "stocks": 
                
                        [
                            {"name": "SG123345", "catagory":"Semigloss","pantoneMatch": true},
                            {"name": "SP9383834", "catagory":"SilverMax","pantoneMatch": false},
                        ]
        
    },
    {   "id":"Pantone 9786754",
        "name":"Pantone 9786754",
        "stocks": 
                        [
                            {"name": "SG123345", "catagory":"Semigloss","pantoneMatch": true},
                            {"name": "SP9383834", "catagory":"SilverMax","pantoneMatch": false},
                        ]

    }


]
```

here is the code im using to create the dropdown

```
var dataStock = (data.stocks.name)
                console.log(dataStock)
                $.each(data, function(i, option){
                    console.log(option)
                    $('#pantoneSelect').append($('<option>').attr("value", option.id).text(option.name));
                })
```

the var dataStock error out because i can't get to the stocks name.

Comment: `data` is an array.. there are 2 things.. `data[0].stocks.name` or `data[1].stocks.name`

Comment: let me add and example of what I am needing.  When the user selects Pantone 12345 from the stocks array for that color will need to be added as text. When user selects a different pantone color, that new colors stocks array will need to be added as text. Should each stock item have an id that matches the id of the pantone? would this make it easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way ?

```js
const data = 
  [ { id   : 'Pantone 12345'
    , name : 'Pantone 12345'
    , stocks: 
      [ { name: 'SG123345',  catagory: 'Semigloss', pantoneMatch: true  } 
      , { name: 'SP9383834', catagory: 'SilverMax', pantoneMatch: false } 
      ] 
    }  
  , { id   : 'Pantone 9786754'
    , name : 'Pantone 9786754' 
    , stocks: 
      [ { name: 'SG123345',  catagory: 'Semigloss', pantoneMatch: true  } 
      , { name: 'SP9383834', catagory: 'SilverMax', pantoneMatch: false } 
  ] } ] 

const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

for (let pantone of data) 
for (let stock of (pantone?.stocks || []))
  {
  myForm.pantoneSelect.add( new Option( stock.name, `${pantone.id}|${stock.name}`))
  }

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()

  if (myForm.pantoneSelect.value != '')
    {
    let [id,stockName] = myForm.pantoneSelect.value.split('|')
      , dataRow        = data.find(x=>x.id === id)
      , stockRow       = dataRow.stocks.find(x=>x.name===stockName)
      ;
    console.clear()
    console.log( `data-id=${dataRow.id}, data-Name=${dataRow.name}` )
    console.log( `stock=${JSON.stringify(stockRow)}` )
    }  
  }
```

```css
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<form action="" name="my-form">

  <select name="pantoneSelect">
    <option selected disabled value="">pick one pantone</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i think you are on the right track, but when i try and run it 'pantoneSelect' comes up as an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pantoneSelect' of undefined at test.js:21"

Comment: i did notice that. could it be because i have the js as a different file im importing? i didn't change your code, just pasted it in to see what would happen, only error i got was the pantoneSelect error

Comment: yeah, HTML form is named "my-form" to match document.forms['my-form]

Comment: im sure its something stupid simple and i just don't see it. thanks for the help

Comment: @Spark85  did you have placed correctly your js `<script> ... </script>` just before the end body tag `</body>` ?

Comment: Hey that was the issue. That was the issue. i was placing it in the top of the dom

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects in your JSON so you want to shift your code appropriately. Your `stocks` is an array of objects as well so you need to adjust accordingly. Try looping through each

```
var names = [];
for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    var stocks = data[a].stocks;
    for (var b = 0; b < stocks.length; b++) {
        var name = stocks[b].name; //Here is each name you're looking for
    }
    var id = data[a].id;
    var name = data[a].name; //Here's the name attribute in the top level object
    //Here you can add a new option element to your select
}
```

Comment: This is close, but right now it will add all the stocks in the whole json. i would only need the stocks for the specific pantone color selected from the dropdown. i added '$('#pantoneStockContainer').append("<p>" + name + "</p>")' after ' var name = stocks[b].name;' and all the stocks in database show up

Answer (score 0):

You have to dig two layers deep. Then use the first layer to grab the id and the second to grab the stock name:

```js
var data=[{id:"Pantone 12345",name:"Pantone 12345",stocks:[{name:"SG123345",catagory:"Semigloss",pantoneMatch:!0},{name:"SP9383834",catagory:"SilverMax",pantoneMatch:!1}]},{id:"Pantone 9786754",name:"Pantone 9786754",stocks:[{name:"SG123345",catagory:"Semigloss",pantoneMatch:!0},{name:"SP9383834",catagory:"SilverMax",pantoneMatch:!1}]}];

$.each(data, function(i, datum){
  if(datum.stocks){
    $.each(datum.stocks, function(i, stock){
      $('#pantoneSelect').append($('<option>').attr("value", datum.id).text(stock.name));
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pantoneSelect"></select>
```